# Splashscreen background is padded

Tags: android, xml, padding, splash-screen

I created a splashscreen for my android app and I set a background image.
The problem is that the background image is padded from borders of screen.
This is the xml code of layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/splashscreen_drawable"
    tools:context="quasiaffatto.myapplication.SplashScreen">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_logo"
    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
    android:text="App title"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: This is the result:]

Why are there paddings on the borders? How can I fix?

Comment: Why are you using this drawable as a mipmap? Have you tried using it as a regular drawable?

Comment: @Tanis.7x I created an image asset with android studio, and it created the image asset as mipmap automatically

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Android Studio is not an image editor and I am not aware of any method of creating image assets within it.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand that really shouldn't be happening. However, my first assumption would be to check if that layout is for an activity or a fragment. If its for a fragment the margins are probably coming from the parent activity, especially if you created this from the default template, which if I recall adds some margin space before the default fragment. If this is not the case then please post more information about the setup of your application.

EDIT: It may be pulling a default margin for the root element from dimen.xml in your res folder. Try setting the margins on the root element to 0dp.

Comment: Yes, this the layout of an activity and I set it with "setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);" in the "onCreate" method..but i don't understand how can i fix the problem.

Comment: It really shouldn't matter, but perhaps try to set the margin on the root element to 0?

Comment: But the root element is the RelativeLayout and I setted all padding values to 0..

Comment: Padding is the space added inside an element before any contained elements. Margin is the space added outside an element before the element itself is drawn. An element's padding can contain part of its background since it is considered part of the element's drawable area, but its margin cannot since it is for spacing it from other elements.

Comment: For the sake of argument, since I don't have much experience with mipmap's, perhaps try setting it background to a solid color and see if the issue still occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The problem was the use of mipmap, using the image as drawable it works perfectly!